# How does the EBP register get saved?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers, stack-frame

I couldn't find much information or specification that suits me, so I have no choice but to ask here.
When we call some function with the `call` instruction and then save the previous stack frame with `push ebp`, how is EBP saved just before it? Does it save automatically when `call` instruction was invoked or how? What is the value stored in this register; what do we `push`?

Comment: `ebp` is no different from other registers in this regard. Pushing it like this saves its current value to the stack. It's logically equivalent to `mov [esp], ebp; sub esp, 4`. To clarify: the value of `ebp` is unaffected by this instruction. The only thing that happens "automatically" in the calling context is the `call` instruction pushing the return address on the stack before it switches `eip` to the new context.

Comment: so I don't really care what is saved in EBP, it just used for position from I subtract or add to get parameters or local variables?

Comment: EBP is traditionally the base pointer for the stack frame, though optimizations and calling conventions may cause it to be used differently. You can technically maintain a stack frame by keeping track of the size of the current stack frame and referencing `esp`. Generally you'll see something like what @500-InternalServerError described in the function prologue and the opposite in the epilogue. How is it saved before? Well if you're storing it on the stack, then that's how. Is it stored on the stack automatically? No. What does `push ebp` do? It stores the previous base pointer on the stack.

Comment: I mean, what is the value in EBP before you push EBP? if I mov 5 to EBP before calling a function and after that push EBP there is no point in that isnt it? What is base pointer and how is it represented? I just don't get it what is stored in EBP when I don't even touch it, but pushing at the very begin in function, what been pushed?

Comment: The `push` is for saving what's there because you're going to change it - matched with a corresponding `pop` towards the end to restore the value from the stack. Typically the very next instruction after `push ebp` will be `mov ebp, esp` to set up `ebp` as a pointer into the current stack frame, for accessing parameters and locals, and you suggest. If a function has no need for that, this setup and teardown of a local `ebp` stack pointer can be omitted.

Comment: Oh, now I guess I understand everything. This pattern is used like that because when you call function from, e.g., another function you should save prev. address for accessing variables in calling function when you exit called function, or whatever value there, if you didn't store address there. It just doubted me, because I didn't understand why I need to save 'nothing', but now it looks clear: saving 'potential' address of prev. stack frame. Thanks for your help

Comment: each thread has its own stack, that is a small piece (hundreds kb to 1MB) and continuous range pre-allocated memory used specifically for aiding function calls. push ebp, means save ebp's value onto the top of the stack, and stack top pointer regester esp will decreased by 4 bytes. your code must respect your own things on stack, and pop them out of stack in reverse order (or just add esp to "discard" them ), for the safe of function call. push ebp usually means you want to keep the register const ( unchanged ) for current function's caller.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError " It's logically equivalent to `mov [esp], ebp`; `sub esp, 4`." I find it troubling to see the order of these instructions here. The `push ebp` instruction will start by lowering ESP, and then writing at `[esp]`. The [comment on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134015/how-does-the-ebp-register-get-saved#comment127459671_72134015) by @Exlife seems to adopt the same mis-understanding.